# Copy string with markup so it looks good on input

Tags: front-end, string-manipulation

How can I copy a string with a bunch of `*Box` expressions without it blowing up into the raw expression?

```
text = Integrate::usage
(* Nice looking String *)

text//Head
(* String *)
```

After copying the output and pasting it into an input cell it looks like

```
 "\!\(\*RowBox[{\"Integrate\", \"[\", RowBox[{StyleBox[\"f\", ....
```

Same thing happens when evaluating in place, so how can I do this without retyping the entire expression?

Comment: Try `CellPrint[Cell[BoxData[Integrate::usage], "Input"]]` then you can mark it with `" "` and such string behaviour is what you need. But I'm struggling with doing this automatically... ;p

Comment: @Kuba Good enough for my needs, thanks :)

Comment: Another possibility is Copy as->Plaint text (Ctrl+Shift+c). Or copy without the first and the last characters.

Comment: @ybeltukov Copy without first and last works great thanks! Plain text copy strips some formatting though.